# Prove for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is some $y \in [0,1)$ such that $x \equiv y \mod \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

So my logic is as such choose any $x$ say $99.05$. Then I can find $y \in [0,1)$ such that $99.05-y \in \mathbb{Z}$ doesn't $y$ have to be $0.05$? Congruences are a little more difficult when you let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Is $\mathbb{Z}$ fixed or am I choosing it so that it satisfies the condition because if I take $120 \in \mathbb{Z}$ then I am in trouble.

How exactly would I start or go about doing this proof. Is my logic correct in understanding the statement?

Comment: You need to show that for every real $x$ there is a $y$ in the interval $[0,1)$ such that the difference $x-y$ is an integer. And yes, in your example $y=0.05$.

Comment: we are assuming this is a reduced congruence right?

Comment: The congruence itself is general, $17.34$ and $41.34$ are equivalent. But there is a *unique* $y$ in $[0,1)$ such that $x\equiv y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, the definition:

$x-y \equiv \mod \mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the set $m = \{z \in \mathbb{Z} \cap \mathbb{R} \ | \ z \leq x \}$ (here I'm using $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$). Since $\mathbb{R}$ is archimedian, $m \neq \emptyset$. Let $z = \max m$ and consider $y = x-z$. If $y\geq1$ then $x-z \geq 1$ or $z + 1 \leq x$, hence $z+1 \in m$, contrary to assumption. Since $z \leq x$, $y\geq 0$ and then $0 \leq y < 1$

Comment: Just to emphasize that I'm not using standard construction of $\mathbb{Z}$ but rather using it as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$